# What does 'CallCnvntn' in metainfo mean?

Tags: metadata, clr, ildasm

I have the following metainfo of my *.exe file:

[image]

But I don't figure out what 'CallCnvntn' means. I have found no information on the Internet.

By the way, may you explain what flags [AutoLayout], [AnsiClass] and [BeforeFieldInit] are used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft programmer that worked on ildasm abbreviated "Calling convention" to make it fit.

The best place to find the exact meaning of the metadata attributes in [the CLI spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).  At breakneck speed: [AutoLayout] is equivalent to the `LayoutKind.Auto` enum value in .NET.  Classes have LayoutKind.Auto by default, structs have LayoutKind.Sequential by default.  [AnsiClass] is equivalent to the `CharSet.Ansi` enum value.  These two type attributes can be changed with the `[StructLayout]` attribute in C# code, normally only done if you write a type to be used in pinvoke declarations.  [BeforeFieldInit] determines when a static constructor of a type has to run.  Present by default, it allows the CLR to delay the call until the code uses a static field in the class.